# Problema ao configurar projeto spring data jpa com Hsqldb

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, hsqldb

Estou tentando configurar um exemplo de projeto usando Spring Data JPA com Hsqldb

Fiz a classe pessoa que seria `model`, a `interface` repositório e uma classe main para rodar.

Eu não criei o banco porque tenho uma duvida se o Spring criara para mim automaticamente conforme o Hibernate tem essa opção.

Classe pessoa

```
package data.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa")
public class Pessoa extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 25, unique = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "sobrenome", nullable = false, length = 25, unique = false)
    private String sobrenome;

    @Column(name = "idade", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private Integer idade;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public Integer getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

}
```

Classe repositório

```
package data.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import data.model.Pessoa;

public interface PessoaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoa, Long> {

}
```

Classe Test

```
package data.teste;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import data.repository.PessoaRepository;

@Component
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    public PessoaRepository getPessoaRepository() {
        return pessoaRepository;
    }

    public void setPessoaRepository(PessoaRepository pessoaRepository) {
        this.pessoaRepository = pessoaRepository;
    }

}
```

Ao executar o main, ele abre uma janela do `Eclipse` para selecionar uma classe dentro de uma lista de algumas classes do `Hsqldb`. Então estou confuso sobre o que pode ser.

Meu arquivo xml de configuração do `Spring`.

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="data.repository" query-lookup-strategy="create-if-not-found"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generteDdl" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitName"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Isso pode ocorrer devido a assinatura do método main estar incorreta ou porque a classe que contém o método main não está definido no Class-Path.

- Assinatura do método main correta:

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
  ```
- Você pode rodar o método main apertando com o **botão direito** em cima do método, e dentro do menu **Run As** e clicar em **Java Application**.
- Também é possível [criar uma configuração](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm) através do menu 
  do Eclipse **Run** >> **Run Configurations...**

Obs.: Será preciso [carregar o contexto do Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-client) dentro do main para poder ter acesso aos beans.

Abs!